# how to add fadein and fadeout effect for first and last elements of jcarousel

Tags: fadein, fadeout, jcarousel, horizontal-scrolling

I am using jcarousel autoscroller for my client. But I need to fadeOut the last element before the scroll occurs. Also fadeIn effect for the first element.

How can I do that ? Somebody please help me.

I tried with the events in http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/events.html but it didn't worked.

Seems like it is for beta testing with version 0.3.0

Any help is appreciable.

Regards
Tomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback functions from http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ for this purpose.

See the demo at http://innovativewebz.blogspot.in/2013/01/fadein-fadeout-effect-to.html

Is this the one that you are looking for ?